# Errors while installing SuiteCRM on wamp in Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sugarcrm, suitecrm

While installing SuiteCRM 7.4.3 on WampServer in Windows 7 64bit, in Stetp 2 (Configuration) I get these errors:

```
( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of MssqlManager::getAffectedRowCount() should be compatible with DBManager::getAffectedRowCount($result) in C:\wamp\www\CRM\include\database\MssqlManager.php on line 2104
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0030  411392  {main}( )   ..\install.php:0
2   0.3320  16332736    require( 'C:\wamp\www\HFTCRM\install\installConfig.php' )   ..\install.php:750
3   0.3320  16333216    DBManagerFactory::getDbDrivers( )   ..\installConfig.php:1655
4   0.3320  16333616    DBManagerFactory::scanDriverDir( )  ..\DBManagerFactory.php:234
5   0.3350  16351992    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\HFTCRM\include\database\FreeTDSManager.php' )    ..\DBManagerFactory.php:200
```

and

```
( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of SqlsrvManager::compareVarDefs() should be compatible with DBManager::compareVarDefs($fielddef1, $fielddef2, $ignoreName = false) in C:\wamp\www\HFTCRM\include\database\SqlsrvManager.php on line 610
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0030  411392  {main}( )   ..\install.php:0
2   0.3320  16332736    require( 'C:\wamp\www\HFTCRM\install\installConfig.php' )   ..\install.php:750
3   0.3320  16333216    DBManagerFactory::getDbDrivers( )   ..\installConfig.php:1655
4   0.3320  16333616    DBManagerFactory::scanDriverDir( )  ..\DBManagerFactory.php:234
```

What is the problem and solution to these errors?

(I have Visual Studio 2012 and MSSQL Server 2012 installed on my system. Just told this in case they cause any conflicts!)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same environment like you, before I upgrade to win 10.
I guess it's the conflicts with MSSQL.
And, pls check your php.ini for mysql extensions.

I'm using xampp server, it works just fine.
But there's a parsing problem with the pdf template->quote group template.

May you good luck.

Comment: What should I check in php.ini? What should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

`display_errors` to off in your php.ini file

or

Click WAMP>PHP>PHP Settings>Display Errors